The unnecessary red block appearing in my code
I wrote the code up by following the instructions given by cplusplus and I don't why the red block keeps appearing in my code. I've installed the latest version of code blocks and also enabled the appropriate compiler. Someone please inform me where I am going wrong.

I've tried several tutorials provided by cplusplus but nothing is really happening.

Your filename has  a .c extension, which is C, not C++. Try naming it .cpp

You also need #include <iostream> or else std::cout will be unknown. Doesn't the red block give you a hint of what's wrong if you hover the mouse pointer over it?

The red square indicates that there're some errors in your code on that line. Also, I guess you must have compiled your code, because the old version(20.03) can only draw a red square when compilation errors occur. CodeBlocks 20.03 can't tell you what's the exact error by clicking on the square; you must look at the build log to see them.
The easiest solution is that you should add a #include <iostream> to your code.
Lastly I strongly recommend you to use a newer CodeBlocks, such as the Nightly ones.
